# SQL Server alter field name

Tags: sql-server, field, alter

I have problem to alter the database field from `datetime` to `integer` with values using SQL Server 2005

My code is...

```
alter table overtime alter column adate numeric(5)
```

while using this query am getting error like this

> Disallowed implicit conversion from
>   data type datetime to data type
>   numeric, table
>   ‘DaiichiPayroll.dbo.Overtime’, column
>   ‘adate’. Use the CONVERT function to
>   run this query.

Any solutions?

Comment: You cannot convert a `DATETIME` to a `NUMERIC` - there is no way to do this "in place" - you need to use the technique that Sachin suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

The server is unable to convert your dateTime column to numeric implicitly. One of the solution is to -

1. create a new column of numeric type
2. convert your data from dateTime column to numeric column by writing an additional query and then
3. delete the dateTime column
4. Rename that newly added column to the same as that deleted dateTime column.

Comment: k, but i having more then 20000 values then how it is possible

Comment: @Lawrance - Added link for you to convert from dateTime to Numeric.

Comment: i don't want to convert the values, i need to modify the existing field like (joindate datime) to (joidate numeric)

Comment: @Lawrance - Yes, but since you already have data in your column which mysql is unable to convert it implicitly. Hence I gave my solution. I am not sure of other way available. Probably someone else might help if this is possible like you want it.

Comment: @Martin - The question was first asked for MySql, there has been edit since then. I have removed the mysql doc link now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst Sachin's answer is probably the best solution you should be aware that the table will still continue to use the storage space for the deleted column [until you rebuild the clustered index](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2009/02/19/72068.aspx).

For that reason it would be quite nice if there was some explicit `convert` syntax that could be run to, for example, change an 8 byte `datetime` column to an 8 byte `bigint` column but AFAIK none exists.

An alternative would be to use SSMS to generate the script for you. This will generate a script that rebuilds the whole table. If you have a large table or many NCIs the blocking overhead of this may well be unacceptable however.